# In my google apps script document.getElementsByClassName returns nothing

Tags: javascript, dom, google-apps-script

Im trying to manipulate the dom with JS to set an elements display attribute to block from none. I've given the element a class name called 'paypal-btn', yet my script fails when I try to do the following `document.getElementsByClassName('paypal-btn')[0].style.display = 'block';`. It gives me an error message saying 'Cannot read property 'style' of null'.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in a WebApp Served page, switch the `<top frame>` just above the console, right of the filter icon, to `<userHtmlFrame(...)>`.

[image]

Comment: These are the options when I click top frame. about blank and script_frame(dev)

Comment: It must be `Script_frame`, strange thing, never heard of that one, in all my Scripts, been using GAS for almost a year now, is always userHtmlFrame